# Why do recursive function in C returns control to main, not previous call?

Tags: c, recursion

I'm writing converter from classic expression notation to Reverse Polish notation. Current piece of code is wrong (works, but does something different than converting), but when I was debugging it I have discovered strange behavior of return.

> Call:
>
> str_to_spol( "(2+3)*(5+6)", a);

```
void str_to_spol(char * str, char * spol)
{
    static int pos = 0;
    while(str[pos]!='\0')
    {
        if (str[pos]=='(') 
        {
            pos++;
            return str_to_spol(str,spol);
            pos++;
        }
        else if(str[pos]==')')
            return;
        else
        {
            spol[pos]=str[pos];
            printf("%c ", str[pos]);
            pos++;
        }
    }
}
```

On the fisrt symbol `'('` function calls itself, we have two functions. Second function works until it meets `')'`, then it returns control to  the end of function, not inside `if`! Why is it so?

In other words output should be:
`2 + 3 * 5 - 6`

And the output is:
`2 + 3`

I'm using gcc 4.8.2

Comment: Are you really asking what the `return` statement does?

Comment: Do not add unrelated tags. Out of curiosity: why did you add the `static` tag?

Comment: `return str_to_spol(str,spol); pos++;` - think about how/if that `pos++` could *ever* be reached.

Comment: @Olaf stepping out in the debugger makes the program to print "right" output. `return` must not **kill** all functions with the same name in stack, only function, where it was called, isn't it? (I remember it, when I was writing recursive factorial)

Comment: C does not have a concept of a _stack_. Only of scope & storage duration. Also the name of a function is not available at run-time, thus your statement is useless. But you are correct: `return` returns (maybe that*s why that name was used ...) from a function. Think about how any code after that statment would be reached. Compiler warnings exist for good reason. Do not ignore them! Still not sure what your problem is.

Comment: @Olaf the problem is that the second call returns control to main, not to the first call. Is it correct?

Comment: Until you can prove different, assume gcc generates correct code. Compile with `-Og` or `-O0` and single-step in a debugger. You will see.

Comment: And you function does not return anything. What is `return str_to_spol ...` supposed to yield??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the second `pos++` in the wrong place. It should be before the *next* `return`. What's happening is that on return having detected `')'`, the same `')'` is detected by every caller, and the call stack drops to the bottom.

There is also a syntax error: the function cannot return a value.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void str_to_spol(char * str, char * spol)
{
    static int pos = 0; 
    while(str[pos]!='\0')
    {
        if (str[pos]=='(') 
        {
            pos++;
            str_to_spol(str,spol);    // <<--- removed `return`
        }
        else if(str[pos]==')')
        {
            pos++;                    // <<--- moved down
            return; 
        }
        else
        {
            spol[pos]=str[pos];
            printf("%c ", str[pos]);
            pos++;
        }
    }
}

int main(void){
    char str[] = "(2+3)*(5+6)";
    char spo[50];
    str_to_spol(str, spo);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
2 + 3 * 5 + 6
```

Comment: That code still is broken. What is `return str_to_spol...` supposed to yield, the function is `void`.

Comment: And @yanpas added missing braces, mybad.

Comment: Because the way unwinding occurs in this recursive function, changing the position of the `pos++;` statement from the `if(...)` block to the `else if(...)` block makes no difference on the output for the input string used. The _only_ change in your answer that makes a difference is the removal of the `return` statement in front of the function `str_to_spol()`

Comment: @WeatherVane - _You have the second pos++ in the wrong place_... I am pretty sure the position adjustment of the `pos++;` you are suggesting has made no difference in the output _for the given input_.

Answer (score 2):

One quick problem:       (*Then onto a discussion about* *[unwinding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23137820/645128)*)

Because the prototype of `str_to_spol` returns `void`

```
void str_to_spol(char * str, char * spol);
```

The line:

```
return str_to_spol(str,spol);
```

causes a compiler error.  *Extraneous return value*.  (I am using C99, CLANG, Windows 7)
It is curious that *gcc 4.8.2* does not also view this as an error condition.  Whether it is allowed on your system or not, when I make the following change (the *only* change), your code seems to work fine, producing the following output: `2 + 3 * 5 - 6`

```
return str_to_spol(str,spol);
```

To:

```
str_to_spol(str,spol);
```

*An interesting note about unwinding* (Why position of `pos++;` does not matter):
Whether the `pos++;` statement occurs in the `if(...)` or the `else if(...)` makes no difference on the output:...,
Because of the way your recursive call unwinds, The output `2 + 3 * 5 + 6` will occur for both of the versions shown below.  (i.e., for this one example, it does not matter if the second instance of the `pos++;` statement occurs in the `if(...)` or in the `else if(...)`):

```
...
if (str[pos]=='(') 
{
    pos++;
    str_to_spol(str,spol); //without return
    pos++;  //original position of statement
}
else if(str[pos]==')')
    return;//execution sequence goes to pos++ in if block
...
```

***Or:***

```
...
if (str[pos]=='(') 
{
    pos++;
    str_to_spol(str,spol);

} //when unwinding (after return call) execution flow goes here
else if(str[pos]==')')
{
    pos++;  //new position of statement
    return; //execution flow goes directly to "}" in if block
}
...
```

This is because entering the second block (`if else(...)`) depends on the conditional exit criteria, `str[pos]==')'`.  Until that is true, unwinding does not occur, and the `pos++;` statement will never occur. Once the condition is met, the statement `pos++` will occur either way as unwinding commences, ultimately resulting in the stated output.  Important to note the output format and sequence depend heavily on the character sequence of the input string: `"(2+3)*(5+6)"`

***Therefore***, the *only* change that was necessary in your original code was removing the `return` statement from in front of `str_to_spol(str,spol);`

Comment: I'm quite confident gcc does complain, too. Either OP did not post the correct code, or there is something weird going on.

Comment: @ryyker writing main here was extra, there is no 'a' in my code, see pastebin link

Comment: removing return type of function is equal to setting int type. If you set int type - the function will be still broken. The control will be returned not to the previous call, but to the main (or convert_to_pol according to my pastebin)

Comment: And void functions may return themselves... Tested with clang-3.6

Comment: @yanpas - I did not mean to suggest you should remove the return type `void` from the prototype, I was suggesting that you remove the `return` statement from in front of the `str_to_spol()` function.  That in fact is (_was_) the _only_ step required for your original post to execute, and produce the stated output.  All of the conversations about moving `pos++;` statement around from one place to another make no difference in this case because what happens during _unwind_.

Answer (score 1):

Your function handles three cases:

1. If character in array `str`, at position `pos` is `== '('`: it makes an recursive step by calling itself, which as @ryyker mentioned is should cause an error as your function has returning type `void`.
2. If character `== ')'`: it terminates by returning control to the caller.
3. Default case: prints the character and increments to next.

Thus, when you hit the first case you should get an error and when you hit the second case, the function returns to the caller, in both cases *"interrupts in the middle"*.

Additionally, `static int pos = 0;` could not be changed, because `pos++;` after the recursive step is not ever reached.

To correct this, move `pos++` before the return statement of the second case and
do not use `return` in your recursive step.

Comment: It returns control to main, not to first invocation, which is strange

Comment: `return` returns to the caller. Whatever that is. It is not necessarily `main`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at these two lines:

```
        return str_to_spol(str,spol);
        pos++;
```

How do you suppose can the pos++ ever be executed?

Comment: It returns control to main, not to first invocation, which is strange. When the control is under first invocation - pos is incremented, isn't it? Maybe I do not understand details of return

Comment: @yanpas: Stop stating that; single-step the code and see the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Thank's everybody for the answers, I would like to conclude with this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void kek()
{
    static int i = 0;
    i++;

    if(i < 5)
    {
        return kek();
        printf("%d ",i);
    }
}

int main()
{
    kek();
    return 0;
}
```

Here we have simple function which should print numbers from `1` to `4`, but it doesn't. Let's see why

1. On the first step we call kek from main, the control is bein held by kek number one (kek1)
2. i is less than five and we return control to previous caller (main), but before returning control, another kek will be called.
3. Second kek (kek2) is called, i is equal to 1, then it increments and if statement returns true. The first line in if block is returns kek(). Now the control will be returned to kek1, but only after kek3 will be finished
   ...
   and so on

To fix our program it's we may rewrite our if block like this:

```
if(i < 5)
    {
        printf("%d ",i);
        kek();
    }
```

Note that our `static int i = 0;` would be equal to 5 after calling kek in main. So future calls wouldn't print anything

PS void functions should not return void expressions! (ISO C forbids ‘return’ with expression, in function returning void)

PPS kek1, kek2 are named so only for convenience

Comment: Sorry to disagree but this holds similar mistakes to your question. a) the `printf` will never be executed, and b) you can't return a function value that has a `void` type.

Comment: @WeatherVane a) yes, I've written that it will be never fixed, but in second block the code was fixed. b) why? returning void functions works fine both with gcc and clang. (I've just ran this code) Can you provide any prooflinks?

Comment: With MSVC `return str_to_spol(str,spol);` gives warning C4098: 'str_to_spol' : 'void' function returning a value. That value is *undefined* so the real damage will happen if you try to subsequently use that returned value.

Comment: Oh, I see, pedantic key suggests this too

Comment: Aside: using `static int i = 0;` will fail when you want to parse *another* expression, since there is no mechanism to reset its value. Better to pass as a function argument, initially `0`, then `i+1` as required, perhaps with the current index returned as the function value.