# output of recursive function in c

Tags: c, recursion, output

I was trying to figure out the output of a simple recursive function that calculate the factorial of a given number inside a function in c. I am confused about the order of execution of 
this `printf` line `printf("returning %d\n", val);`

I expected the output of this code to be :

```
called with par = 4
called with par = 3
called with par = 2
called with par = 1
returning 24
24
```

But the output is:

```
called with par = 4
called with par = 3
called with par = 2
called with par = 1
returning 2
returning 6
returning 24
```

Code:

```
int factorial(int n);
int main(void)
{

printf("%d",factorial(4));

}


int factorial(int n)
{
    int val;
    if ((n == 0) || (n == 1)) 
    {
        printf("called with par = %d\n", n);
        return 1;
    }

    else 
    {
        printf("called with par = %d\n", n);
        val = n * factorial(n - 1);
        printf("returning %d\n", val);
        return val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Every time you call it, it returns back to where it was called. After it calls itself, it returns to itself. Is that surprising?

Comment: Can you explain *why* you think your output is correct?

Comment: Each call except the base case (`n == 0 || n == 1`) will print *both* "called with" and "returning".

Comment: And if you learn how to use a debugger to step through your code statement by statement, and stepping into the recursive calls, might help you understand better what's happening.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I understand how recursion work, i am asking how does the returning line work. first time the function takes the integer input it will call itself and do the math so when 4 is called `val=4*3*2*1` now the `printf` part in the function should print only after the calculation is done or I mean after the `factorial(n-1)` comes to an end. why does is return 2 then 6 then the final value.

Comment: @user253751 i didn't ask about how recursion work.

Comment: There is an explanation of [how recursion unwinds here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34698301/645128) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23137820/645128)

Comment: If you understand how recursion works then you should know why it is printing the intermediate results.

Comment: Okay, thanks @user253751

Answer (score 3):

If we take your example of `factorial(4)` then it goes something like this:

```
factorial(4)
    print "called with par = 4"
    val = 4 * factorial(3)
        print "called with par = 3"
        val = 3 * factorial(2)
            print "called with par = 2"
            val = 2 * factorial(1)
                print "called with par = 1"
                return 1
            print "returning 2"  // 2 * 1 = 2
            return 2
        print "returning 6"  // 3 * 2 = 6
        return 6
    print "returning 24"  // 4 * 6 = 24
    return 24
```

Each call where `n > 1` (and unfortunately where `n < 0`) will print both `"called with..."` *and* `"returning..."`.