# Why is this code correct?

Tags: c, recursion

```
#include <stdio.h>
void reverseSentence();

int main()
{
  printf("Enter a sentence: ");
  reverseSentence();

  return 0;
}

void reverseSentence()
{
  char c;
  scanf("%c", &c);

  if( c != '\n')
  {
    reverseSentence();
    printf("%c",c);
  }
```

I tried out this code and I know it is correct, but i don't know why the recursion works. It seems a bit non-intuitive. Could someone please shed some light on why it works? Also, what is `\n` doing exactly?(This is where i think the answer to my question lies). Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it with a debugger?

Comment: Perfect example of when and how not to use recursion.

Comment: There is an explanation of how recursion works _[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23137820/645128)_

Comment: change `scanf("%c", &c);` to `scanf(" %c", &c);`

Answer (score 2):

The name `reverseSentence` is rather bad for recursion.

What happens is that it reads one character and saves it in a local variable.

Then if the character is not a newline (==`\n`) it will call itself again. This will happen recursively until a newline is entered. After that, it will print its character.

Since at the end you will traverse up through the call-stack, this will call the different instances in reverse order. → the string will be outputted in reverse

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you are trying to type the word "elf" (with the "\n") character at the end.

The program should print: "fle".

1. The program enters reverseSentence().
2. The program scans 'e', it's not '\n', therefore enters reverseSentence(). c='e'
3. The program scans 'l', it's not '\n', therefore enters reverseSentence(). c='l'
4. The program scans 'f', it's not '\n', therefore enters reverseSentence(). c='f'
5. The program scans '\n', it is '\n', therefore exits reverseSentence() and goes to the last called instance  of reverseSentece() in (4).
6. The last call in reverseSentence() stoped just before printf, it now prints c. c in the last call (4) was: 'f'. It prints f and exits. It goes to the previous call of reverseSentence() in (3).
7. Just like before it prints c='l' and exits.
8. It goes to the previous call or reverseSentence() in (2). It prints c='e' and exits.

I hope that helped

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` "consumes" the char it reads, that means that in the next call of the function the line would be 1 character shorter since the previous one has already been used by the previous recursive call.

Comment: I mean to ask what is the code doing to reverse the string?

Comment: @1upon0 by how recursion works, when the recursive function is called since ```scanf``` consumed a character the string will be shorter. This process will continue until ```\n``` is found, when this happens the function that found it finishes and the previous one continues triggering a chain reaction that will print all the chars found.